# Cannot sign in users in Hartl Tutorial Chp 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have two failing rpec tests that state that there are two links that are not present. the exact messages are:

```
Failure/Error: it {should have_link("Sign Out", href: signout_path)}
       expected #has_link?("Sign Out", {:href=>"/signout"}) to return true, got false

Failure/Error: it {should have_link("Profile", href: user_path(user))}
   expected #has_link?("Profile", {:href=>"/users/1"}) to return true, got false
```

when I visit the site locally I notice that when I type in the url to a specific user the page comes up but the menu changes do not appear as they should for a signed in user.  So I tried signing in as another user and I notice that it does not allow it telling me my user info is invalid.  So that leads me to believe that my user authentication is not working properly, but truthfully what do I know since I am still learning.  My Code looks like:

application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @title = "Sign In"
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6}

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.digest(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = User.digest(User.new_remember_token)
    end

end
```

and my sessions_helper

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(remember_token)
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

this is the menu change that is supposed to happen when a user is signed in

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "Sample App", root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", "#" %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", "#" %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign In", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

It's as if my application doesn't see that anyone is signed in.  I can post another files needed I will be glad to post.  I am just not sure how this isn't working given that no runtime exceptions come up.  As always any advice is appreciated.

here is the routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
```

Comment: what about `config/routes.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `signed_in?` method in `sessions_helper.rb` was mistyped:

`!current_user.nil?` should have been `current_user.nil?`.

Also I changed the create method in my sessions controller from:

```
 def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

to:

```
 def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

these changes have now allowed the application to work as expected.